# Mixins inside media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries, mixins

My question is probably trivial but I couldn't find an answer.
I want to change some mixins inside media queries but they don't seem to work.

```
@mixin boxSize
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
//Media Queries//
@media (max-width: 400px)
  @mixin boxSize
    width: 50px
    height: 50px
```

Comment: Do you specified element you want to set this styles for?

Comment: i did it in img
  @include boxSize

Comment: i just want to swap this values in mixins for width<400px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
@mixin boxSize
    width: 200px
    height: 200px

    @media (max-width: 400px)
        width: 50px
        height: 50px
```

But this code looks like mix of sass and scss syntax, the sass mixin is here: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: This work's but i want to organize the list of changes in each media query including this mixin. Is this possible?